# Extra measures above staff in Hungarian Rhapsody No. 6

Tags: piano, notation

[image]

So there is an extra two measures on top of the measure 58. What does that mean?

Comment: Funny it's called 'in Db', but part of the piece is in key sig C#...

Comment: The measure numbers are not in the image you posted.  Which one is measure 58?

Comment: @Tim Perhaps the manuscript was written in C# major, and for that reason the editor of this particular edition wanted to preserve that notation, while at the same time usually Db major is substituted these days, so everyone knows the piece by the Db major name instead of the C# major name.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - o.k., but it 'modulates' from C# to Db on the music. Strange?

Comment: @Tim that is very interesting. Perhaps a whole new question on what's going on there would be cool. I don't have any ideas at this time why that would make sense. If it were music on a non-keyboard instrument from before wide adoption of 12 ET, then maybe that would make some sense, but for keyboard music in any tuning it seems like a notation change only. Perhaps there's a reason for a notation change there.

Answer (score 6):

The one says "2da volta" means "second repeat".  You play the given bars in the second  repeat while playing the main variant (of the top staff, presumably) otherwise.

The "Ossia" means "Other": optionally, you can play the small variant instead of the main variant below it.

Comment: I'm going to convert the question about measure numbers to a comment, since that's the appropriate place for such questions, and you probably won't be able to comment yourself yet. And I'm letting the rest of the answer stand (and upvoting it) since it's solid information and probably answers the question regardless of which measure is 58. Welcome to Music.SE and good first answer!

Comment: Being pedantic, do you mean 'first repeat' rather than 'second repeat'?

Comment: @Tim Doesn't "2da" seem more likely to mean "second" rather than "first"? Oh, I see what you're saying. Maybe this is regional but in my experience the phrase "first repeat" when talking about music means the first time the section is played, not the second time. Yes, it's abuse of the word "repeat", but that's how people say it. If someone said "second repeat" and meant the third time through, that would really confuse me. Likewise with "first repeat" meaning the second time through, but "on the repeat" would mean the second playing to me.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - yes, when something is repeated, it HAS to have been done the first time, surely. So a second repeat HAS to be the third rendition!

Comment: @ToddWilcox  - AND! a first time bar is called that for a good reason!!  It isn't  called a first repeat time bar...

Comment: @Tim All I'm saying is with every musician and teacher I've ever worked with, speaking American English, "first repeat" means the first time through, "second repeat" means the second time through, "on the repeat" means the second time through. In general, "repeat" does not mean the first time **except** when the word "first" comes before it. It might make no logical sense, but it's the way people seem to use it in my neck of the woods.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that's fair enough It's lost something in the translation! I'll bear that in mind when I get some gigs over the pond! Here's hoping...

Comment: I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means the second time you play the right hand slightly differently, sort of arpeggiated. 'Volta' means time or occasion.

'Ossia' is just an alternative part, to be chosen instead of the original under it. Usually an easier option, but ossia doesn't literally mean easier!