# How to write "Play this line, OR this line" with conventional music symbols

Tags: sheet-music

In a music sheet, how could I write down "*play this line* OR *this line, as you like*".

The reason is that if the player is skilled, they will choose to play the first line, but if not, they will prefer the second one.

Is there any defined way to write that? Any specific symbols? A convention?

Comment: This is a completely off-topic comment, but since you seem so keen on not misgendering the player you can always use "they" which is the most common gender-neutral pronoun. It's just friendly advice.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That is called an "Ossia", it is a musical term for "alternatively". Which means the player can either play the alternative passage or the original passage. The Ossia is frequently used in Liszt's pieces. The Urtext for Balakirev's Islamey also contains many alternative passages.

Here is an example of an Ossia notation in Liszt's Hungarian Rhapsody No.6 in Db Major.

[image]

An Ossia passage could sometimes be notated only for one clef like in the example. Although I'm not sure if you could change the use of the sustain pedal in the alternative passage, it's better to ask a professional or a teacher. Or someone who might know.

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, _this_ is the better answer since it actually shows what an ossia looks like.

Comment: The ossia is usually a simplified version of the original, in that it contains fewer notes, so will be easier to play, without losing much substance. Although sometimes it's just a slight variation. As such, the pedalling will be exactly the same - assuming the player can pedal correctly, it will work just as well as the original.

Comment: So we can't change pedal instructions in the Ossia passage?

Comment: it's also used in Holst's music quite a bit...  (e.g. St Paul's Suite)

Comment: I saw quite a few in his St.Paul's Suite.

Comment: @IsaacYangHaoTung you can do what you want, as long as you make it sound right. Keeping the pedal instructions will help you to make it sound right, but it is not necessary.

Comment: @Tim , an ossia might sometime have exactly the same note, but one (or more) octave higher/lower, as for some instruments, it may be easier (like cello, to avoid high thumb positions).

Comment: You can change pedal instructions whenever you want They are not necessarily obligatory, but are like fingerings, to hopefully make it go as well as it can. Seasoned players will know when and how to pedal, and that may vary with each performance. If the pedalling works in the original it will still be valid in an ossia. Ears are usually good judges!

Comment: @Tim, one question about the Ossias' in this passage. In the bars at the bottom of the page, there is an Ossia passage for the Treble clef, but exactly which one.?

Comment: If you look very carefully at the notes involved, there are clues. Work it out!!  There's a 50/50 without looking.

Comment: @IsaacYangHaoTung the thing at the bottom of the page isn't an ossia, it's tagged *2da volta*, and in fact [this exact instance has been asked about before, here](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43758/extra-measures-above-staff-in-hungarian-rhapsody-no-6/43762)

Answer (score 8):

This is called an [Ossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossia).  It's an extra line of music that floats over the music.

Comment: or under if the notes are really high...

Comment: @dalearn What do you mean?

Comment: @Karlo  If the notes are well above the staff it is common to put the Ossia below the notes.  Think some violin music where the Ossia is down an octave from the notes written.